# Как исправить внешний вид ссылки?

Tags: joomla, javascript

Создал ссылку на почтовый ящик в материале joomla, но когда захожу на сайт и открываю страницу, вместо нормального текста отображается вот такой код javascript'a

```
document.write(''); 
document.write(addy_text85678); 
document.write('<\/a>');
//-->\n
```

Решил просмотреть исходный код при отображении сайта, там тоже вместо простой ссылки встроен сценарий javascript.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Джумла, чтоб не палить адерес ящика гнусным спамерам заменяет его название на скрипт, который записывает в данную позицию адрес почты, хотелось бы увидеть в вопросе:

1. код фрагмента материала, где прописан ящик,
2. фрагмент этой части страницы, с захватом кода по бокам, чтоб понятнее было.

По по вашему же вопросу сложно сказать, что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расширения -> Менеджер плагинов

Вырубем "Content - Email Cloaking"

Профит

Comment: на русский это так переводится-Контент - Скрытие электронной почты?

Answer (score 0):

В хедере формируемого сообщения укажите такой тег:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html; Charset=Windows-1251">
```

Comment: мне наоборот надо чтобы страницы были с кодировкой utf-8